# Java: How to define an swing JButton action with a loop?

Tags: java, swing

I try to create a small pocket calculator app, that has 15 buttons.

All of the buttons shall have an action to add the corresponding number or calculation sign to the calculation JTextField.

I have created a JButton array that contains all the buttons, and then create a loop to assing an action to each of the buttons, as all the buttons are actually the same.

Each button has a text which defines its text (0-9 +-*/=).

```
        final int NUM_BUTTONS=15;
        //Buttons in ein Array legen, um die Actions zu vereinfachen.
        var buttons = new JButton[NUM_BUTTONS];

        buttons[7] = new JButton("7");
        panel.add(buttons[7], c) ;
```

Then there is a loop for all the buttons (except the last one, that is = and gets another action)

```
        for(int button=0; button < NUM_BUTTONS-1 ; button++) {
            buttons[button].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    calculationTextField.setText(calculationTextField.getText() + (buttons[button].getText()));
                }
            });
        }
```

And now it does not compile, because of:
/home/clinden/studium/IdeaProjects/JAPR02_A/src/main/java/japr02/Calculator.java:100: error: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final
calculationTextField.setText(calculationTextField.getText() + (buttons[button].getText()));

So how do I actually get it to use button not as a local variable?

a foreach does work, but I cannot used it, as the last button does need another action and not both (tried to overwrite it, but it will add two actions actually).

Comment: you are trying to add actionlisteners, but I don't see you actually creating Buttons, I would start with that

Comment: @Stultuske I just did not write it in ... addded it - just one of the 15 buttons. They are all the same just in an array and with a text.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74925295/522444) is one way to do this sort of thing, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20037116/522444) may prove helpful (although without the listeners).

Comment: There's no need to create `NUM_BUTTONS` worth of `ActionListener`s. Just have *one* instance of a private class that implements that interface and add that instance to all buttons. btw, your loop will miss the last button (the `- 1` is incorrect)

Comment: I would recommend creating *two* ActionListeners, one for the buttons, and the `.`, dot, and another for the operations. You can use a Set to distinguish and decide which listener to add.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33973521/522444) is the example that I was looking for that demonstrates using 2 or 3 actions for a collection of JButtons all created dynamically.

Comment: Since Java 8, I prefer to use [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) when implementing [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) interface.